# Automação de Python Tela de Bloqueio do Windows

Tags: python, script, login, windows-10, pyautogui

Criei uma automação em python com Botcity. Porém meu problema é que o PC que fica o programa (seria pelo agendador a chamada) ele bloqueia em 10 min a tela (não tem como tirar esse bloqueio). Esse script iria rodar a noite a tela está bloqueada. Tem alguma forma de eu manter essa tela ativa via script? Ou fazer a aplicação rodar mesmo a tela estando bloqueada? Desde já agradeço

Tentei usar PyAutoGUI para simular uma pessoa, mas sem sucesso.

Um pedaço do código:

```py
class Bot(DesktopBot):
    def action(self, execution=None):
        # Uncomment to silence Maestro errors when disconnected
        # if self.maestro:
        #     self.maestro.RAISE_NOT_CONNECTED = False

        # Fetch the Activity ID from the task:
        # task = self.maestro.get_task(execution.task_id)
        # activity_id = task.activity_id

        # Opens the BotCity website.

        data_atual = date.today().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
        nome_arquivo_log = str(data_atual) + "_log.txt"
        if path.exists(nome_arquivo_log) :
            f = open(nome_arquivo_log, "a")
        else:
            f = open(nome_arquivo_log, "x")
        try:
            self.execute(r'executavel')
            self.sleep(20000)
```

Comment: Pode postar o codigo , dessa forma podem ajudar observando o código e entendendo como é a lib usada.!

Comment: A tela bloqueada não impede que processos sejam executados, contando que o computador não entre no modo sleep, tudo continuará rodando normalmente. Não deveria interferir pelo que você comentou.

Comment: @RenanGomes Bloqueia e pede senha o script tem partes que simula um usuário. Chamar o exe ele chama a tela estando bloqueada mas no momento que existe a interação de interface não vai mais, ou seja somente chama o exe e para

Comment: @Alline e se ficar  mexendo o mouse  1 pixel infinitamente mesmo assim ocorre o bloqueio ? sim ,li que comentou sobre mas pensei algo aleatório ou um agendador de tarefa pro sistema.

Comment: @stack.cardoso não funciona assim. Tem que usar a função da API do Windows [`SetThreadExecutionState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) que permite que a aplicativo informar ao sistema que está em uso, evitando assim que o sistema entre em suspensão ou desligue a tela enquanto o aplicativo estiver em execução. Quando acordar eu escrevo uma resposta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques  só conheço essa api [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)  que permite interagir com o windows, creio que seja essa a resposta é uma das apis mais indicada e documentada para interagir com o sistema. outra que pesquisei e não seu muito o detalhes é a [caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) mas é um executavel sem muitos detalhes a nao ser a documentação da mesma.

Comment: Só para complementar tem a api [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)  como todas são para o sistema windows e mencionada em livros forence e pentest pode ser uma direção no entanto nao tenho total certeza de que posa funcionar  essa questão.

Comment: Obrigada. Vou testar as soluções passadas volto para contar. Muito Obrigada pela ajuda